# Problema com o Fetch Lazy [ Spring Boot ] [ Thymeleaf ]

Tags: spring-boot

Bom estou com um problema em relação a minha classe que está na sessão do Spring
Erro:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
```

Possuo um classe que representa objeto em sessão e esta anotada:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Test{
   private Map<Item, Long> items = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   public Colletion<Item> getList() { return items.keySet(); }
   // ...
}
```

Sendo que ele possui um LinkedHashMap de Item que esta assim :

```
public class Item {
   private Modelo modelo;
   // Esse metodo retorna uma Soma de Value da Classe Price
   public BigDecimal getPrice() { return modelo.valorSomado(); }
   // ...
}
```

Que por sua vez é minha entidade Modelo usa anotação da spec JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Modelo extends BaseEntity<Long>{
   @ElementCollection
   private List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<>();
   // ...
}
```

E dentro da Classe Price contém :

```
@Embeddable
public class Price {
   @Column(scale=2)
   private BigDecimal value;
   // ...
}
```

Bom ao chamar o value da classe price na view, meio que por ele não ser @Embeddable(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) ele não consegue carregar para mim lançando essa exception acima, mas como eu posso contornar isso usando o DEFAULT Lazy do hibernate?

VIEW uma parte onde esta lançando o erro:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${beans.test.list}">        
    <td th:text="${item.modelo.title}" /> <!-- Até aqui funciona -->
    <td class="numeric-cell" th:text="${item.price}"/> <!-- Aqui Lança um erro -->
```

Já tentei usar o AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer usando o filtro para entityManager sempre ficar aberta mas não deu muito certo não para mim ele persiste o erro não sei se pode ser por causa de eu estar usando o Thymeleaf ou por estar usando de forma errada esse filtro usei dessa maneira mas não funcionou.

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {  
  @Override
  protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[]{ 
       new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()
    };
  }
  // ...
}
```

Ah estou utilizando as seguintes ferramentas e frameworks no Projeto

- Spring Boot (Security, MVC, DATA, etc)
- Thymeleaf
- Maven

Alguém poderia me ajudar.
Fico Agradecida desde já.

Comment: Olá, qual o motivo especifico para contornar o problema usando DEFAULT Lazy config do hibernate?, por que usar um filtro que nem você tentou pode trazer problemas de performance piores ainda do que você configurar o fetch como Eager

Comment: Então @LeonardoVillela eu gostária de fazer com que o JPA(Hibernate) apenas  busque quando necessário. E por que o filtro seria uma abordagem tão ruim assim ? Pois em alguns lugares estão comentando da utilização do mesmo para que eu possa lidar com o Lazy dentro do Spring.

Comment: Não falei que seria uma abordagem ruim, mas que traria algum nível de complexidade, sendo assim se o uso do lazy fosse dispensável, seria desnecessário o uso do filtro, vou postar uma resposta explicando como lidar com o filtro :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá como conversamos nos comentários, uma possível solução é anotar seu método `getList` com `@Transactional` do Spring, pois assim o seu método ira rodar dentro de uma transaction evitando esse problema, em código seria algo do tipo:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Test{
   private Map<Item, Long> items = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public Colletion<Item> getList() { return items.keySet(); }
   // ...
}
```

Obs: Podem ocorrer alguns problemas se você não tiver configuração para uso de transações, se esse for o caso escreva nos comentários que eu te ensino como fazer.

Comment: Bom então ainda persiste o mesmo erro quando eu acesso a página. Talvez deve ser o fato que eu não estou sabendo configurar o Spring devidamente para o uso da transação como você explicou, pode me mostrar como se configura ele ?

Comment: Claro, mas ocorreu qual erro?

Comment: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "item.price" (test/items:37)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)

Comment: Bom isso é uma parte de stacktrace .